# Under what conditions does LAContext.biometryType return .none?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, lacontext

I try this function to get device's available biometry type.
The first time I enter the screen I call this function and get nil.
Then I redirect to another page and come back. The this function can get the value.

```
func checkOptionBio() -> BiometricType?{
    let context = LAContext()
    var bioReturn :BiometricType? = nil
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let biometryType = context.biometryType
        if biometryType == .faceID {
            bioReturn = .faceID
        } else if biometryType == .touchID {
            bioReturn = .touchID
        }
    } else {
        bioReturn = .touchID
    }
    return bioReturn
}
```

What is limitation of this function and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for [`LAContext biometryType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/2867583-biometrytype) it states:

> This property is set only after you call the `canEvaluatePolicy(_:error:)` method, and is set no matter what the call returns. The default value is `LABiometryType.none`.

So that's the first issue you need to fix. You must call `canEvaluatePolicy(_:error:)` before you attempt to access the `biometry` property. You will need to pass in an appropriate `LAPolicy` based on the needs of your application.

If `canEvaluatePolicy(_:error:)` returns `true` then you can get the `biometryType`. At this point you can still get a result of `.none` if the device is not setup to use Face ID or Touch ID.

One possible update to your method could be:

```
func checkOptionBio() -> BiometricType? {
    let context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var bioReturn: BiometricType? = nil
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let biometryType = context.biometryType
            if biometryType == .faceID {
                bioReturn = .faceID
            } else if biometryType == .touchID {
                bioReturn = .touchID
            } // else == .none
        } else {
            bioReturn = .touchID
        }
    } else {
        // device has no enabled biometrics
        if let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    return bioReturn
}
```

This assumes you want to support only biometrics (touch id or face id) and not just fallback on a user passcode.